# How to handle `|| chr(38) ||` in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a SQL script which is returned by Oracle, this output script then needs to be run in SQL server. I know it might sound odd but we are in the process of moving from Oracle to SQL server. so the problem is few of the lines from this script have statement like

```
insert into media values('Mumbai','C123','MP3','Gully ' || chr(38) || ' Gang','','');
```

When the above statement is tried in SQL server then error is thrown saying

```
  Incorrect syntax near '|'.
```

How do I fix this?

I tried `set define on/off` but of no use.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle uses its own SQL variant, SQL Server uses its own. What does `||` do? Have you tried finding the equivalent in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I got to know concatenation operator in SQL is different but i was wondering if there's a way to handle this without major modification in the Oracle output script.

Comment: It's a different product. There's no way to avoid changes. Besides - what Oracle output script? Are you trying to load the data by using a dump instead of eg, directly replicating the data? Or exporting it to flat files and importing them? Such a script is very fragile, takes a *lot* more space than eg a CSV file and is far slower to execute than importing a flat file. Each INSERT operation results in a separate transaction log entry. When using BULK INSERT or bcp to load data on the other hand use minimal logging

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you intend:

```
insert into media
    values('Mumbai', 'C123', 'MP3',
           concat('Gully ', char(38), ' Gang'), '', '');
```

Some comments:

- Why not just use `'Gully & Gang'`?  On my keyboard at least, `&` is easy to type.
- In Oracle, the `''` are `NULL`s.  Those are different in SQL Server.  It is not clear which you want, but I might guess `NULL`.
- List the columns explicitly on `insert`.  That is a best practice.

Comment: The mentioned insert statement is part of a script which is outputted from a oracle script. If I had a choice then obviously would chose to type `Gully & Gang`.
This output script then needs to be executed in SQL server and at that moment I'm coming across this issue.

Comment: Yes.  Failing to convert `''` to NULL for SQL Server will come back to bite you.  You should go so far as to put constraints on the column to not allow `''`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, using '+' instead of '||'.

```
insert into media values('Mumbai','C123','MP3','Gully ' + char(38) + ' Gang','','');
```

All expressions are preferably of type string.

Comment: This can easily fail if the parts have different types and one of them is numeric. Numeric types have higher precedence, so T-SQL will try to convert the strings into numbers

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you. I added a note.

Answer (score 0):

When converting from Oracle to SQL Server you should use (or have on-hand for reference) [SQL Server Migration Assitant For Oracle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54258), which will translate that statement for you as

```
INSERT MEDIA(
   NAME, 
   A, 
   B, 
   C, 
   D, 
   E)
   VALUES (
      'Mumbai', 
      'C123', 
      'MP3', 
      'Gully ' + ISNULL(char(38), '') + ' Gang', 
      NULL, 
      NULL)
GO
```

Oracle silently converts `''` to NULL, and SQL Server does not.  So that's a required part of the conversion.